# How to output to a csv file using csv.write and add headers- Python3/boto3

Tags: python-3.x, csv, boto3

I am trying to write the value of my bucket.name, and obj.key to a csv file with its respective value in its respective column.

When I run the code below, it only outputs the values without a header.

I am trying to put a header to each .format object but don't know where to start.

Here is my code:

```
def load_into_csv(years):
    for year in years:
        with open('/my_path/{}_V123_files.csv'.format(year), 'w', newline='') as file:
            for buckett in s3.buckets.all():
                for aobj in buckett.objects.filter(Bucket=bucket,Prefix=PREFIX):
                    if year in aobj.key:
                        #VALUES I WANT TO SEPARATE BY VALUE
                        file1= '{}:{}:{}:{}:{}'.format(buckett.name,aobj.key, aobj.last_modified)
                        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
                        writer.writerow([file1])

years=['2017']
load_into_csv(years)
```

ANY IDEAS or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to easily associate columns with header, I'd suggest using `csv.DictWriter` like described in docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter.

It allows you not only associate values to headers as a simple dict, without any need to write strings manually, but also it has convenient `writeheader()` method which will include your header in file for you.